# How tensorflow lite use bicubic?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm using Tensorflow lite for Android, official Python code uses the following code before using `TF.lite.Interpreter`, but this code uses the TensorFlow module, which is not available in Android Java. How should TensorFlow Lite implement the bicubic Resize method?

```
img_resized = tf.image.resize(img, [width, height], method='bicubic', preserve_aspect_ratio=False)
img_input = img_resized.numpy()
reshape_img = img_input.reshape(1, width, height, 3)
tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(reshape_img, dtype=tf.float32)

# load model
print("Load model...")
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_name)
```

official Python code use model.tflite, I only found these two methods in Android TensorFlow Lite, not bicubic:

```
ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR
ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TFLite does not have bicubic resize. Three options here:

1. If part of preprocessing - do it on java side
2. Try to use selected TF ops: add `converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [ tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, # enable TensorFlow Lite ops. tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS # enable TensorFlow ops. ]` and add `implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:0.0.0-nightly'` to your build.gradle. [Details](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select)
3. If 1 and 2 do not work - you will be offered by friendly community to implement yourself

Comment: What's out for this dependency.It adds significant size to final apk.

Comment: By the link there is solution for dramatic size reduction. Once set up build env for Tensorflow gives a lot of opportunities for custom builds, just saying.